# Can I use EnableStatic for configuring an IPv6 addres (using WMI)?

Tags: wmi, ip-address, ipv6

I would like to use WMI (in C++) to configure a static IPv6 address.

Configuring a static IPv4 address is working fine using `EnableStatic`, which is part of a WMI class named `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration`.

Can anyone help me configure an IPv6 address using WMI? I have been looking for example code, but have not found any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

According to the [Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration documentation on the MSDN web site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), this API supports *limited* IPv6 functionality (looks like it's limited to just reading addresses on an interface) starting in Windows Vista.

You might also want to look at this article: *[IPv6 and IPv4 Support in WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa822883%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*.