# Setting static IPv6 IP-address with WMI (C#)

Tags: c#, wmi, ipv6

I'm building this IP manager tool using the ManagementClass, but I'm facing issues when trying to set an IPv6 address through WMI.

The relevant part of the code I'm using is the following:

```
ManagementBaseObject ipParams = wmiManager.GetMethodParameters("EnableStatic");
ipParams["IPAddress"] = ipAddresses; // { "fe80::fcd8:70b5:89f3:825d" }
ipParams["SubnetMask"] = netmasks;   // { "64" }
wmiObject.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", ipParams, null);
```

When an IPv6 address (standard format) with a subnetmask (integer format) is passed to the EnableStatic method, it doesn't seem to apply it.

I thought it might have problems validating the subnetmask, but I'm not really sure if there is a full subnetmask notation for IPv6. Then again it might just as well be validation for the IP-address or something completely different.

I'm pretty new to this ManagementClass thing and I haven't figured out a way to read out errors. If anyone has some pointer for this, do tell.

Comment: did you read this ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360230/can-i-use-enablestatic-for-configuring-an-ipv6-addres-using-wmi

Answer (score 0):

Per @Codelgnoto [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4953965/1569434), which points to @Mike answer, it is impossible to set this on Vista and higher; IPv6 has only limited support, such as *reading* the value - not setting it. See Mike's post for brief (surprising) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Array of all of the IP addresses associated with the current network adapter.

**Starting with Windows Vista**, this property can contain either IPv6 addresses or IPv4 addresses. For more information, see I[Pv6 and IPv4 Support in WMI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394217(v=vs.85).aspx).